# cur = mysql.connector.cursor() AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'connector'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pycharm

I am trying to make a simple login form using python, flask and a mysql database in the pycharm IDE.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL


mysql = MySQL()

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'regform'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

mysql.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def reg():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/home', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def reg2():
    email = request.form['uname']
    password = request.form['psw']
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    # cursors.execute('SELECT * FROM signup WHERE email = '"+email+"'and password = '"+ password +"'')
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM signup WHERE email = %s AND password = %s', (email, password))

    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        return 'no user'
    else:
        return 'welcome'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

There were no errors but there is no output. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You say you had no errors but the title is an error. Where is the offending code?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs of Flask-MySQL (https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you have to do the following to get your cursor:

```
mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
```